# Installing a package starts installing updates

Tags: fedora, software-installation, yum, dnf

So I just installed Fedora 34 and did the following:

`sudo dnf install powertop`

However, rather than installing the package, it begins downloading updates. Because I'm using a metered connection, I'd like to simply install that package. Same thing happens with `yum`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
sudo dnf install powertop -C
```

to tell `dnf` not to update the metadata cache.

Note that `yum` redirects to `dnf`, so it's really the same command, and the latter should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Oftentimes installing (the latest version of) a package requires updating packages on which it depends. That seems to be what is happening here. You might look for an older version to install if you don't want to update anything. Very much not recommended, but it is your own fun when it breaks.